# Finding the sum of numbers between any two given numbers

Tags: arithmetic

I tried to derive this type of formula and ended up with this . But it's not holding true for all the numbers. Can you please tell what[image] I've done wrong !!

Comment: It took me ten minutes to understand the question. Your error is probably in the interpretation of b/w.

Comment: Are you counting $\alpha$ in your sum? If so, then you need to replace $\alpha$ by $\alpha-1$ in your formula. To see why this is, consider the sum of the numbers between $2$ and $3$. This is $2+3=5$. this can be written as $(1+2+3)-1$. In the proof, however, you seem to have assumed that this is $(1+2+3)-(1+2)$ which gives the incorrect answer of 3, not 5.

Comment: So can you tell me the fully revised formula then

Comment: @Amritanshu if you need the sum between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ including both, you need to replace $\alpha$ by $\alpha-1$. If you wish to exclude both, you need to replace $\beta$ by $\beta-1$.

Comment: You are so close.  1) is the some of the numbers including 1 and alpha.  Two is the sum to beta.  So subtracting them is the sum from alpha +1 to beta.  This is probably not what you want.  You probably want either from alpha +1 to beta -1.  Or from alpha to beta.

Comment: What *exactly* does b/w mean?  If you think that out you will get it.

Comment: b/w is the short form of between

Answer (score 13):

Between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there are $\beta - \alpha + 1$ numbers. We need
\begin{align*}
S &= \alpha + (\alpha + 1) + \cdots + \beta \\
&= \beta + (\beta - 1) +\cdots + \alpha
\end{align*}
Adding vertically, we have 
\begin{equation*}
2S = (\beta-\alpha+1)(\alpha+\beta)
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{equation*}
S = \frac{(\beta-\alpha+1)(\alpha+\beta)}{2}
\end{equation*}
This "reverse and add" technique is due to Gauss and can be used to sum any arithmetic progression as well.